# Couldn't capture volume key events in Android TV 9 from Android version 9

Tags: android

We have AndroidTV running on Android version 9. We need to get key events for volume keys when pressed from  remote. Unfortunately couldn't get volume key events from Android version 9. But we can get volume key events from AndroidTV version Nougat 7.0. Question: How I need to capture volume key events in AndroidTV versions 9 [pie]?

```java
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Key down, code " + event.getKeyCode());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + event.getKeyCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    }
    return true;
}
```